# Blender 2.8 to ThreeJS GLTF Specular

Tags: three.js, blender, specular

I have a model in Blender 2.8 ( and 2.79 ) with a grass texture on a plane.  It's a field.  No matter what I set the metalness and roughness to, when viewing it in ThreeJS there's always a whitish sheen on the field when looking at it from certain angles according to the sun position.

I think setting the specular color to black would remove that sheen, but I'm guessing this isn't currently possible to do because ThreeJS StandardMaterial doesn't control specular color..

So, basically, is there anyway to control the specular color on a ThreeJS StandardMaterial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an environment map? Or change the color of your directional light?

Comment: Those are both solutions.  I've thought about what effect changing the directional light would have, but the light can't be changed.  The environment map may work for my situation, but I'm starting to understand why standard material is the way it is and I'm working with it.